Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
I am trying to make a web server for the Mineflayer API for my coding project. It is hosted using the free plan on render.com, and I use a cron job to keep it awake. However, when I send the bot creation request to it, it gives this error, and then continues execution:
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
{
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

I tried looking for errors in my code, but I have not found any. The server goes through a switch statement to determine which path to take, and this one is triggered:
case "create":
  let [username, ip, port] = data.split(","); // For now, we only support offline mode.
  let id = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
  let bot = mineflayer.createBot({username: username || `Bromine_${id.slice(0, 8)}`, host: ip, port: (port || 25565)});
  bot.messages = [];
  bot.on("message", function(msg, pos) {this.messages.push({jsonMsg: msg, position: pos})});
  bots[id] = {bot: bot};
  var response = {success: true, id: id};
  break;

Edit
The error message is sometimes longer, and may contain more information:
Error: write ECONNRESET
    at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
    at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:962:11)
    at Socket._write (node:net:974:8)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Framer.ondata (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/minecraft-protocol/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/readable.js:705:22)
    at Framer.emit (node:events:517:28)
    at addChunk (/opt/render/project/src/node_modules/minecraft-protocol/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/internal/streams/readable.js:321:12)
{
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write'
}


How do you send the request? Where do you see this error and is that the complete stack trace?

@JensV To test it, I sent the request through a web browser. I see this error in the render logs.

And that's the only thing you see? Because that error message seems way too short

@JensV Of the error, yes. There is the chance the render logs aren't showing the full error.

Does it work when you run it locally or only when deployed? Are you also sure that the server you're connecting to is reachable from there?

Also note that your template string "Bromine_${id.slice(0, 8)}" does not work as expected. You need backticks for that syntax to work instead of double-quotes

@JensV Yes that was a silly mistake of mine. I will fix that error and try it again.

@JensV also, it sometimes emits a more verbose error message.

@JensV It works locally

It seems the error is the equivalent of the connection reset error that can occur when trying to join a Minecraft server. The issue probably came from using an aternos server, since the actual server it is hosted on changes every time.
